# Saving parameters to DB Django Rails-equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

as i'm switching from rails to django, i was wondering if there is a similar way to save all parameters to database at once in django. in rails i use

```
foo = Bar.create! params[:foo]
render :json => foo
```

is there equivalent in django or do i have to assign every parameter to the corresponding db field?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

You'd basically end up saving the form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method